# While using Positioned widget the Argon button works only from bottom side

Tags: flutter

While the button is pressed the only half the bottom part of the button working
I am working on voting bar where I use Stack at the top and use two Argon button one is left side of the screen and one is right side of the screen, And both button are half cropped
So when I tapped to button It not responsive and looks its not wokring but its work when we tap on bottom part of the Argon button
Here a
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O37tE.jpg)

```
return Stack(
  overflow: Overflow.visible,
  children: [
    Container(
           children: [
                Text(post.good.toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/angel.svg',
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: 28,
                    width: 28,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
              color: Colors.amber),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 30,
        ),
      ),
    
    //Bad BAR
    AnimatedPositioned(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
      right: userBad ? goodBar : badBar = 0,
     
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/devil.svg',
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(post.bad.toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
              ],
            ),
    
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15)),
              color: Colors.amber),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * badAns,
          height: 30,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
        top: -25,
        left: -65,
        child: ArgonButton(
          //Good Button
          onTap: (startLoading, stopLoading, btnState) async {
            if (post.goodList.contains(user.uid)) {
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Posts")
                  .document(post.id)
                  .updateData({
                "good": FieldValue.increment(-1),
                "goodList": FieldValue.arrayRemove([user.uid]),
              });
            } else {
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Posts")
                  .document(post.id)
                  .updateData({
                "good": FieldValue.increment(1),
                "goodList": FieldValue.arrayUnion([user.uid]),
              });
              if (post.badList.contains(user.uid)) {
                Firestore.instance
                    .collection("Posts")
                    .document(post.id)
                    .updateData({
                  "bad": FieldValue.increment(-1),
                  "badList": FieldValue.arrayRemove([user.uid]),
                });
              }
            }
          },
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 40,
          elevation: 5,
          hoverElevation: 10,
          width: 140,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 45),
            child: Text(post.type == 'Mudda Post' ? 'SUPPORT' : 'HEAVEN',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: userGood ? Colors.amber : Colors.grey,
                )),
          ),
          borderRadius: 30,
        )),
    Positioned(
        top: -25,
        right: -65,
        child: ArgonButton(
          onTap: (startLoading, stopLoading, btnState) async {
            //FirstPart of checking
            if (post.badList.contains(user.uid)) {
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Posts")
                  .document(post.id)
                  .updateData({
                "bad": FieldValue.increment(-1),
                "badList": FieldValue.arrayRemove([user.uid]),
              });
            } else {
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Posts")
                  .document(post.id)
                  .updateData({
                "bad": FieldValue.increment(1),
                "badList": FieldValue.arrayUnion([user.uid]),
              });

              if (post.goodList.contains(user.uid)) {
                Firestore.instance
                    .collection("Posts")
                    .document(post.id)
                    .updateData({
                  "good": FieldValue.increment(-1),
                  "goodList": FieldValue.arrayRemove([user.uid]),
                });
              }
            }
          },
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 40,
          elevation: 5,
          width: 140,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 65),
            child: Text(
              post.type == 'Mudda Post' ? 'NOT SUPPORT' : 'HELL',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: userBad ? Colors.amber : Color(0xff958B8B)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          ),
          borderRadius: 30,
        )),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Hi! Did you try to use `Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, ...)`? It should help

Comment: @Mol0ko yes I tried but its still not works